# Preselect Items in Multiselect-Listbox (MVC3 Razor)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a problem with the preselection of Items in a listbox.
I am using razor view engine with mvc 3. I know there are a few posts with the same issue but they don't work for me.

Code in Class:

```
public class Foo{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    public string Name{
       get{
           return _name;
       }

    public int Id {
       get{
           return _id;
       }

}
```

Code in Model:

```
public class FooModel{

    private readonly IList<Foo> _selectedFoos;
    private readonly IList<Foo> _allFoos;

    public IList<Foo> SelectedFoos{
         get{ return _selectedFoos;}
    }

    public IList<Foo> AllFoos{
         get{ return _allFoos;}
    }

}
```

Code in cshtml:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Flatschels, 
        Model.AllFlatschels.Select(fl => new SelectListItem {
             Text = fl.Name,
             Value = fl.Id.ToString(),
             Selected = Model.Flatschels.Any(y => y.Id == fl.Id)
   }), new {Multiple = "multiple"})
```

I tried lots of other things but nothing worked. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I can't really explain why, but I managed to get it working. Either of these worked:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFoos,
            new MultiSelectList(Model.AllFoos, "ID", "Name"), new {Multiple = "multiple"}) 

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFoos, Model.AllFoos
            .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Name, Value = f.ID }),
                new {Multiple = "multiple"})
```

The problem seems to be that the Selected property on SelectListItem is ignored, and instead the `ToString()`(!) method is being called, so if you need to add this to your `Foo` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.ID;
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with being able to persist across requests (which will be flattened to strings to be passed over the wire), but it's a bit confusing!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it working. Although only the second code worked and it seems to me, that it is not because of the overridden ToString(). My Id Property was an int and I added a Property Key returning a unique string (guid.ToString()).

Comment: Weird. Can't explain the ToString thing, but glad you got it sorted :-)

Comment: It was definitly because of the ToString(). Just posted a Question in the Microsoft Forum and hope to get an answer and maybe an info why (and how long) this is they way it currently is.

Comment: Same behavior on Razor for MVC4. Borderline on bug (at least for ListBox(), which does not expect a Model to compare elements on).

Comment: Worked for me, too! For whatever reason, the following did **not** work: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFoos, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllFoos), new {multiple = ""}` (where in my case, `Foo` is an enum, not a tuple object. The only change I needed to make was `DropDownListFor` -> `ListBoxFor`

Answer (score 0):

In MVC5 you can directly use ListBoxFor with multiselect. Make sure while loading the view your selectedItem should have list of items.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new MultiSelectList(Model.Item.ToList(), "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```