# Use DataAnnotations to force a DropDownList populated from my model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations

Is there a way use DataAnnotations to tell Razor to render a DropDownList and populate the choices from a specific field in a specific entity?

Specifically I am capturing a "Calendar Year" property in my View and would like it to be a DropDownList.  I am doing this currently by passing the years into my view via the ViewBag and then calling "DropDownListFor".  I was hoping for a way to define it in my ViewModel and them simply call "EditorFor".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way to do it with a DataAnnotation, but you don't need to use the ViewBag, you could pass the values in, like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFoos, Model.AllFoos.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Name, Value = f.ID }))
```

(Note: This uses ListBox, [taken from an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858679/preselect-items-in-multiselect-listbox-mvc3-razor/5859732#5859732), but should be similar for DropDownList).