# ASP.NET MVC (razor) Listbox multiselect values to string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two multi-select list boxes; one with months and one with years such as the following:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeMonths, Model.TimeframeMonths)
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeYears, Model.TimeframeYears)
```

I'm saving the both values to the database as a comma separated list (string/nvarchar).  The values are being like this: **Months:** 1,3,7; **Years:** 2002,2005

For some reason when I pull the values back out to the form, the months are pre-selecting in the listbox fine, but the years are not.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT** - Additional code samples:

**Controller - Manage**

```
public ActionResult Manage(Guid id)
    {
        var list = _listService.GetList(id);

        var model = LoadModelFromObject(list);
        model.TimeframeMonths = GenerateMonthDropdown();
        model.TimeframeYears = GenerateYearDropdown(model.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeYears.Split(','));
        model.DaysOfWeek = GenerateDaysOfWeekDropdown();

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Controller - 'Helper'**

```
private IList<SelectListItem> GenerateYearDropdown(string[] selected)
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var startYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 10;

        for (int idx = startYear; idx < startYear + 11; idx++)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value = idx.ToString(),
                             Text = idx.ToString(),
                             Selected = selected != null && selected.Contains(idx.ToString())
                         });
        }

        return list;
    }
```

**View**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframe)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframe)
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeMonths, Model.TimeframeMonths)
@*@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeYears, Model.TimeframeYears)*@
@Html.ListBox("IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeYears", Model.TimeframeYears)
```

Comment: What does `Model.TimeframeYears` return? I mean the values. It must return type of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but I cannot see what values it has.

Comment: @tugberk The Model.TimeframeYears has the `IList<SelectListItem>` and the Value and Text of each SelectListItem are the year (2002)

Comment: Could you provide sample values illustrating the problem of the `IncludeGuestsArrivedInTimeframeYears` and `TimeframeYears` properties?

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `Selected` property of `SelectItemList` class to true for the options which you want to be pre-selected.

Example:

```
@{
    var foo = new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Foo 1", Value = "1", Selected = true },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Foo 2", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Foo 3", Value = "3", Selected = true }
    };
}

@Html.ListBox("foo", foo)
```

In this case, Foo 1 and Foo 3 should appear as pre-selected. The above code generates the below html markup:

```
<select id="foo" multiple="multiple" name="foo">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Foo 1</option>
    <option value="2">Foo 2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Foo 3</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:**

First of all, replace this code:

```
list.Add(new SelectListItem {
     Value = idx.ToString(),
     Text = idx.ToString(),
     Selected = selected != null && selected.Contains(idx.ToString())
});
```

with this code:

```
list.Add(new SelectListItem {
     Value = idx.ToString(),
     Text = idx.ToString(),
     Selected = true
});
```

Then run the app. If all the options are pre-selected, then I bet that this `selected != null && selected.Contains(idx.ToString())` does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: Okay, I changed it up a little bit.  I have a method called **GenerateYearDropdown** which I modified to take an array of strings, which I pass in.  The array is being passed in correctly, and setting the _selected_ value of each list item, but it's not displaying those selections on the form.

Comment: @mmillican did you try out the above code? It works on my machine and should work on yours, too. The problem is with your code, post it as well.

Comment: I updated it and set `Selected = true` for all the entries and it's still not selecting them.  Any other ideas?  Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: Looks like they're not being selected.  I was hoping to be able to send it to the view from the controller but maybe I won't be able to do that.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it

```
@Html.ListBox("categoryId", new MultiSelectList(ViewData["categories"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "CategoryName", Model.tIdx_ProductCategories.Select(x => x.CategoryId).AsEnumerable()))
```

Explanation:

1. `categoryId` - would be name of control, when rendered as html
2. `ViewData["categories"]` - is list of categories with `Id` and `CategoryName` properties
3. `Model.tIdx_ProductCategories`  carries the list of category ids to be selected in list box.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems (e.g. here [Preselect Items in Multiselect-Listbox (MVC3 Razor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858679/preselect-items-in-multiselect-listbox-mvc3-razor)) the Razor engine happily **ignores** the Selected property and compares the list from the model and the supplied option list by calling ToString() on the objects from the model and using string comparison to select.

What I cannot explain to myself is **why** this behavior is used with Html.ListBox(), which does not use any model and expects a collection of SelectListItem.

Think it's a bug, but it does not seem to have been addressed recently.