# MVC DropDownList selected value not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I am using MVC 5.

I have my ViewBag for list as

```
ViewBag.TitleList = new SelectList((new string[] { "Mr", "Miss", "Ms", "Mrs" }), contact.Title);
//contact.Title has selected value.
```

then I tried converting the array to `SelectListItem ( to no avail)`

On the View it looks like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, ViewBag.TitleList as SelectList, "Select")
```

also I tried

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title", ViewBag.TitleList as SelectList, "Select")
```

The list loads successfully but the `Selected Value is Not selected`.
How to Fix this problem?

**Update**
The culprit was ViewBag.Title matching my model.Title. Renamed my model property to something else and it worked. Arrgh!

Comment: Using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` if the value of `model.Title` is (say) "Miss", then the 2nd option will be selected (you do not need the 2nd parameter in the `SelectList` constructor). Check that the value of `Title` matches exactly one of the option values.

Comment: Yes the value in Title matches with the ones in the list

Comment: May be this is a duplicate to that post.

[Possible duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858679/preselect-items-in-multiselect-listbox-mvc3-razor

Comment: Thank you for your update. I have spent 30 minutes wondering why my Title dropdown wasn't being Selected. I never knew this was an issue before today - thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set value of the `Title` property in the controller:

```
ViewBag.TitleList = new SelectList(new string[] { "Mr", "Miss", "Ms", "Mrs" });
viewModel.Title = "Miss"; // Miss will be selected by default
```

Another possible reason (and the correct one, based on the comments below) is that `ViewData["Title"]` is overridden by another value. Change name of the `Title` property to any other and everything should work.

Comment: The `Title` already has value while loading. it is part of edit method.

Comment: @Ruchan, then the value of `Title` does not match one of those 4 values (perhaps check for white space), or your trying to do this in a loop

Comment: @Ruchan, Is it any chance you're setting the title of the page using `Title` as a key: `ViewBag.Title = "Edit"`? Try to change the property name to any other.

Comment: I thought the same and changed the model property name and tried, but still the same

Comment: Ok, at the end it was eventually the ViewBag.Title..... so mad right now. Edit your answer so i can choose it as correct one.

Answer (score 2):

When a value is not specified (i.e. "Id"), DropDownListFor sometimes does not behave properly. Try this:

```
public class FooModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

var temp = new FooModel[] 
{
    new FooModel {Id = 1, Text = "Mr"}, new FooModel {Id = 2, Text = "Miss"},
    new FooModel {Id = 3, Text = "Ms"}, new FooModel {Id = 4, Text = "Mrs"}
                       };
ViewBag.TitleList = new SelectList(temp, "Id", "Text", 2);
```

EDIT: other sololution

```
var temp = new []
{
    new SelectListItem {Value = "Mr", Text = "Mr"}, new SelectListItem {Value = "Miss", Text = "Miss"},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "Ms", Text = "Ms"}, new SelectListItem {Value = "Mrs", Text = "Mrs"}
};
ViewBag.TitleList = new SelectList(temp, "Value", "Text", "Miss");
```

Comment: See Ivan, when you solve a problem all by yourself, it's called _sololution_.